# ProgramData environment variable not recognized wixsharp

Tags: c#, wixsharp

I tried to delete a folder at uninstall but it does nothing.
specifying the path though, get it to work.
Not working:

```
 public void OnAfterInstall(SetupEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsUninstalling)
            {
                
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"CommonAppDataFolder\myFolder");
                if ((bool)(dir?.Exists))
                {
                    dir?.Delete(true);
                }
                
            }
        }
```

Working:

```
public void OnAfterInstall(SetupEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsUninstalling)
            {
                
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\ProgramData\myFolder");
                if ((bool)(dir?.Exists))
                {
                    dir?.Delete(true);
                }
                
            }
        }
```

Edit:
I tried this code and I'm getting the very same error:

```
        var programFiles = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%");
        var manifestFile = Path.Combine(programFiles,@"\My Company\myFile.man");

        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(manifestFile);
        if ((bool)(fInfo?.Exists))
        {
            FileSecurity security = fInfo.GetAccessControl();
            security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null),
                FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, AccessControlType.Allow));
            fInfo.SetAccessControl(security);
        }

        var CMDCommand = $@"/C wevtutil im {manifestFile}";
        Process.Start("CMD.exe", CMDCommand);
```

I tried also this:

```
var programFiles = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
    var manifestFile = programFiles + @"\My Company\myFile.man";
```

Running this code on `C:\` is working fine..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expand the environment variable to get the actual path

```
var common = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramData%");
var yourFolder = Path.Combine(common, "myFolder");
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(yourFolder);
```

Notice how to to retrieve an Environment Variable from its string you need to put the string between %, also you could get an Hashtable with all the Environment Variables defined on your machine (custom or standard) using

```
var envs = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
```

Consider also the alternative (or probably *a better choice*) highlighted by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) in its comment. **Environment.GetFolderPath** is  a method that receives an enum  **SpecialFolder** and returns the path for the special folder requested.

This is a better choice because it not depends on an Environment Variable that could be changed o removed and thus creating a possible buggy situation.

```
var common = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though it is not working.

Comment: Actually, Path.Combine(common, "myFolder"); return "myFolder"

Comment: Not sure what is the problem. Surely you should have an environment variable called %ProgramData%. Can you check the return value of Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables using the debugger?